# Crear una lista por voz en JavaScript usando la API SpeechRecognition

Tags: javascript, api, lista

Estoy intentando crear una lista en JavaScript que agregue las tareas mediante la voz. He usado la API SpeechRecognition.

El problema que tengo es que solo se queda en pantalla la última frase que digo y quiero que se agreguen una debajo de otra.

No sé si será del propio uso de la API (he intentado entender la documentación) o si será que me falta alguna expresión en el código.

Así es como lo estoy haciendo:

```
const microfono = document.querySelector('#microfono');
const salida = document.querySelector('#salida');


microfono.addEventListener('click', ejecutarAPI);


function ejecutarAPI(){


const SpeechRecognition = webkitSpeechRecognition; 
const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();

recognition.start();

recognition.onstart = function() {
    salida.textContent = 'escuchando...';  
};

recognition.onspeechend = function() {
    salida.textContent = ' ';
    recognition.stop();    
};


recognition.onresult = function(e) {
    console.log(e.results[0][0]);

    const {transcript} = e.results[0][0];
    const speech = document.createElement('li');
    speech.innerHTML = `${transcript}`;
    
    salida.appendChild(speech); 
    
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fíjate que en el método *onstart* (al iniciar la grabación) estás reemplazando el contenido del elemento salida por un texto fijo: "escuchando..."

```
recognition.onstart = function() {
    salida.textContent = 'escuchando...';  
};
```

Y lo mismo the pasa en *onspeechend* (al terminar la grabación):

```
recognition.onspeechend = function() {
    salida.textContent = ' ';
    recognition.stop();    
};
```

Si haces eso, te estás cargando todo lo que hubiese previamente en dicho elemento.

Es decir, cada vez que le das a grabar, **estás eliminando todo el contenido** que había en el elemento salida previamente.

Por eso siempre se queda uno solo, el último que añades.

Te recomiendo que crees otro elemento que se llame por ejemplo "estado", y ahí sea donde reemplaces el textContent por "escuchando" y "esperando micrófono", por ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias @ÁlvaroFranz era eso.